# Read a cookie value from another domain using jquery

Tags: jquery, cookies

I have created an application in which i have saved cookie on another domain called `server1.xyz.com`. I want to read that cookie in my site on another domain using jquery. How can i do it. I have used following code but it gives null value for the cookie.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

alert($.cookie('cronimagename', {
    path: '/',
    domain: 'serverl.xyz.com'
}));
document.getElementsByName('Orders.Custom_Field_Custom1')[0].value = $.cookie('cronimagename', {
    path: '/',
    domain: 'serverl.xyz.com'
});

</script>
```

Comment: Is it even possible to request cookies from another domain? wouln't that cause some security issues?.. Aah you can share a cookie through multiple domains :) didn't know what. cool,  have you done that?

Comment: You can't. You can use Chromium with disabled security settings to develop or test. But it will only work locally in reality.